# Make my set proxy script better

Tags: beginner, bash

Below is my bash script to setup a proxy, I am by no means an expert in bash. I suspect there is a better way to write this, any tips would be appreciated.

Is there a better way to do nested while-loops and if-statements?

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e    

#functions
function yesno() {
  while read -n1 -r -p "[y/n/QUIT] > "; do
    case $REPLY in
      y|n) return;;
      q) echo; echo; exit 1;;
      *) printf "\nERROR - Invalid response, please enter Yes OR No.\n";;
    esac
  done
}

function startover() {
  printf "\n\n\e[1m\e[31mStarting Over...\e[0m\n"
  sleep 2
  unset proxyport proxyhost
}


    shopt -s nocasematch
    while true; do
      printf "\nIs a proxy required to access outbound \e[1m\e[7mHTTP/HTTPS\e[0m sites?\n"
      yesno
      if [[ $REPLY == "y" ]]; then
        printf "\n\nPlease enter your proxy url\nExample - \e[1m\e[7mproxy.example.com:8080\e[0m\n"
        while read -r -p "Proxy > " proxy; do
          if [[ $proxy =~ ^https:// && $proxy =~ :[0-9]{1,5}$ ]]; then
            printf "\nERROR - HTTPS with a port is not supported, please re-enter without '\e[1m\e[97m\e[41mHTTPS://\e[0m' prefix\n"
          elif [[ $proxy =~ ^(https?://)?([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9\.]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.[a-z]{2,5})?.((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))?(:[0-9]{1,5})?$ ]]; then
            if [[ $proxy =~ :[0-9]{1,5}$ ]]; then
              proxyport=${proxy##*:}
              proxy=${proxy%:*}
              echo "Port entered $proxyport"
            elif [[ $proxy =~ ^https:// && ! $proxy =~ :[0-9]{1,5}$ ]]; then
              proxyport=443
              echo "URL starts with HTTPS, assuming $proxyport"
            else
              proxyport=80
              echo "No port entered, assuming $proxyport"
            fi
            proxyhost=${proxy##*/}
            break
          else
            printf "\nERROR - \e[1m\e[97m\e[41m$proxy\e[0m is not supported please try again\n"
          fi
        done
        printf "\nCreating Proxy Settings\n"
        sleep 2
        printf "Proxy Hostname: \e[1m\e[97m\e[44m$proxyhost\e[0m\nProxy Port: \e[1m\e[97m\e[44m$proxyport\e[0m\nDoes the information above look correct?\n"
        yesno
        if [[ $REPLY == "n" ]]; then
          startover
        fi
      fi
      break
    done
    shopt -u nocasematch
```

**Update 4/6/17**
I have improved the regex so it now supports IP and hostnames, i am still working on actually setting the proxy settings.

Comment: I'm no expert in bash either so I don't feel very qualified to post an actual answer. One thing I noticed is your `case` statement only allows for lowercase `y` `n` replies. I would consider making it `[Yy]) ...` and `[Nn]) ...`

Comment: And just to be nitpicky you are missing the shebang at the beginning of your script.

Comment: thanks for the input, since i am invoking 'shopt -s nocasematch' the user input is no longer case sensative, so Y and y will both match my case.

Answer (score 1):

#### Messy formatting

The first thing I noticed about this script is the messy formatting.
Poorly formatted code is hard to read and maintain.

#### Extract complex conditions to helper functions

The code has many complex conditions.
It would be more readable if you extracted them into helper functions.

For example, instead of this:

> ```
>   if [[ $proxy =~ ^https:// && $proxy =~ :[0-9]{1,5}$ ]]; then
>     # ...
> ```

You could introduce this helper function:

```
isHttpsWithPort() {
  [[ $proxy =~ ^https:// && $proxy =~ :[0-9]{1,5}$ ]]
}
```

And then use it with:

```
if isHttpsWithPort; then
  # ...
```

I recommend to change all complex conditions like that,
and the code will be more readable,
thanks to self-explanatory names of the functions.

#### Make `yesno` return success or failure

After calling the `yesno` function you check the value of `REPLY`.
This is not very ergonomic.
You could make `yesno` return success for "yes" and failure for "no":

```
yesno() {
  while read -n1 -r -p "[y/n/QUIT] > "; do
    case $REPLY in
      y) return 0;;
      n) return 1;;
      q) echo; echo; exit 1;;
      *) printf "\nERROR - Invalid response, please enter Yes OR No.\n";;
    esac
  done
}
```

When written this way,
instead of this:

> ```
>     yesno
>     if [[ $REPLY == "n" ]]; then
>       startover
>     fi
> ```

You could simplify to:

```
yesno || startover
```

Similarly, instead of this:

> ```
>   yesno
>   if [[ $REPLY == "y" ]]; then
> ```

You could write:

```
if yesno; then
```

#### Loop not looping

The main `while` loop doesn't actually loop, so it should be removed:

> ```
> while true; do
>   # ...
>   break
> done
> ```

Comment: great input, i'll make the changes and update as I have added some additional changes since my last update